# How did Eren lose his memories?

Tags: attack-on-titan

We all know by now that Eren

> has the Coordinate power, which means that he should possess memories of everything (origin of titans and such).

How does he not remember everything until much later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, the memory inheritance power of Coordinate would only work for the bloodline of the Reiss royal family.

> Nevertheless, it seems that only the Reiss bloodline can activate this ability from the beginning, since Uri and Frieda Reiss showed signs of being aware of that knowledge immediately after obtaining the Coordinate, while Eren was only able to see some vague memories of Frieda after years of having received it.

One of the characteristics of the Coordinate is that its effects are linked to bloodlines.

The memory manipulation didn't work on several bloodlines that were not among the common people in the walls,

> (...) it is known that at least the Ackerman bloodline, the Asian clan, and the noble families are immune to this mental manipulation due to not sharing a common bloodline with the majority race within the walls.

So by not being a Reiss by birth, the coordinate is more or less dormant on Eren.

Source: http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Coordinate

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even though he is not of royal blood and doesn't remember about the coordinate, but shouldn't he still remember memories from his father as the attack titan at the very least?

For example, Ymir ― even though she was still a teenager at the time and might not (or might, I might be wrong on this) have sufficient knowledge on the actual happenings of Marley and Eldian affairs and plus being a mindless titan for 60 years ― seems very aware of the current situation and Reiner and Bertholt's mission after eating Marcel. So, it's still not clear why Eren doesn't remember anything.

Comment: please reply here if you get answers to this, eren technically must remember grisha's and eren kruger's memories atleast and all of the previous attack titans. it may be because of the dominant influence of the coordinate but since armin is about to be the collosal, will that mean, it will solve everything for the people inside the walls?

Answer (score 0):

The powers of the Coordinate can be fully awoken by a member of the royal bloodline (the Reiss family).

Eren is not part of that bloodline. Plus in the anime he is still new to all this and thus not used to the titan power.

Explained in the Manga, the members of the Reiss family who were passed on the Coordinate power immediately knew "all the answers" and all the history before the walls.

Interestingly enough however, after someone obtained this "God ability", he/she always refused to discuss it. The reason still remains unknown, but I believe it to be one of the most dramatic points of the series.

Answer (score -5):

It's because his father made him forget (with the shot).

Comment: Please expand your answer with sufficient references. One liner answer is not acceptable here.

Comment: No, the shot was meant to turn him into a titan.